# Determiner “(a) little” with singular countable words

Tags: grammaticality, determiners, countable-nouns

Page [308 of Practical English Usage](http://horarioscentros.uned.es/archivos_publicos/qdocente_planes/306142/littleandfew.pdf) reads

> We use the determiner *(a) little* with singular (**usually uncountable**)
> words.

What use with singular countable words is it implying?

I know it's always possible to treat nouns as uncountable in a jocular tone, as in [*This is much too much car for me*](https://books.google.es/books?id=Io49C8R-bo8C&lpg=PA218&dq=%22too%20much%20car%22&hl=es&pg=PA218#v=onepage&q=%22too%20much%20car%22&f=false) or the structure "too much **X** for so little **Y**", where both or either can be countable nouns.

Comment: As I pointed out on the ELL forum, you have misread the sentence.

Comment: The link you provided does indeed say "usually uncountable", but I'm not aware of any count nouns selected by "(a) little".

Comment: @Kate Bunting I don't think GJC has misread the sentence. 'usually uncountable" seems to imply that the determiner (a) little can sometimes be used with countable nouns.

Comment: @BillJ it's always possible to treat nouns uncountably in a jocular tone, as in _This is much too much car for me_ https://books.google.es/books?id=Io49C8R-bo8C&lpg=PA218&dq=%22too%20much%20car%22&hl=es&pg=PA218#v=onepage&q=%22too%20much%20car%22&f=false

Comment: @GJC Really? Then why ask if you think you believe you know the answer? Now supply a sentence containing "(a) little" with a count noun in Standard English.

Comment: @BillJ  _Stout realized , even while designing this third Skycar , that it was too much airplane and too little car ._

Comment: That is a non-count use of "car" used in an abstract way

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, the **determiner** (a) little cannot be used with countable nouns.